# Running TensorFlow model on OSX

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im developing a demo application. I want to load a tensorflow model into a flask app, and build a simple text recommender.

I would like to load this model https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4, I have saved the model locally and im doing this.

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.saved_model.load("./universal-sentence-encoder_4/")
```

The error this gives me is

```
2020-06-28 02:17:00.746648: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7f988abbff40 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-06-28 02:17:00.746736: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
```

Im wondering is it possible to run TF models locally on OSX? Or do they need to be done on GPU instances.

Comment: Those are just informative messages, not errors.

Comment: Ahh gotchu. Actually there was another issue that was causing my flask service to fail. All I saw were these errors so I thought this was the problem . got it working now.,